# How to retain Google+ share count after server migration?

Tags: google, google-plus

I have made a URL change with my site. After that it affects all my G+ share counts for specific page - it resets to 0. I want to migrate all the original share counts from old URL to new URL. I did set the G+ share button's `data-href` pointing to old URL like what said from other researches that I saw, but still it doesn't reflect the original count. Can anyone help me regarding this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you should establish 301-redirects from the old to the new pages, specially from those old, which were g-plused. Together with changing of data-href redirects should do the job.